# Refresh desktop after registry edit without restarting explorer.exe

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch, vbscript

I am editing the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`Key and `Desktop`Value. The new location does work intentionally once explorer has been restarted, though this closes all other functions of explorer unrelated to the desktop.

Using Batch and VBS scripts is there a way to refresh the desktop after editting this registry without restarting explorer.exe?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following PowerShell script instead of directly editing the registry to change the special folder paths, there won't be a need to restart the Explorer shell.

[path - Set location of Special Folders with PowerShell - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709398/set-location-of-special-folders-with-powershell)

The PowerShell script uses the `SHSetKnownFolderPath` API call. After redirecting the desktop shell folder, press <kbd>F5</kbd> on the desktop to refresh the views.